# Angular 10 | ngrx Effects | Unit Tests | Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-unit-test, angular10

After upgrading the Angular project to Angular 10, ngRx effects unit tests started breaking. Following is the error after upgrade:

[image]

Running into the same issue, Follow the solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 16):

Hopefully, this can be useful to someone someday.

After multiple hours of debugging and search found the root cause of the issue.

The issue occurs when the `target`is set to `ES5` in `tsconfig.base.json`.

By default, Angular 10 get scaffolded with the setting as `ES2015` with which it works fine. But, that solution will not work for legacy browsers ie. IE11.

How do we set the target to `ES5`, so that project runs in IE and also the unit tests get passed?

Well, the solution was very simple.

Simply set the target setting in `tsconfig.spec.json` to `ES2015` (defined below), without changing any configuration in base `tsconfig`. That worked like charm for me and the project gets compiled builder with `ES5` settings and unit tests run fine with `ES2015` setting.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine"],
    "target": "ES2015"
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Output:

[image]

Happy coding and debugging :-)

Thanks,

Comment: This probably prevents running the tests in IE11 though? Any idea how to archive this?

Comment: Thanks so much Mr Kumar! Do you know whether this issue has been reported already? It would be great to be able to run those tests with ES5 as target. Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 Thank you. Sorry, no info on if this has been logged as a bug.

Comment: @ManishKumar I have created a discussion on the rxjs GitHub repo (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/discussions/5976). Feel free to visit it or add any comments if you think appropriate. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In my project this was caused by using `TestScheduler.run` - so changing

```js
it('should test some observable', () => {
    const scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => expect(actual).toEqual(expected));
    scheduler.run(helpers => {
        const testObservable$ = getYourTestObservable();
        helpers.expectObservable(testObservable$).toBe('(a)', {a: 'some value'});
    });
});
```

to

```js
it('should test some observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const testObservable$ = getYourTestObservable();
    expect(testObservable$).toBeObservable(cold('(a)', {a: 'some value'}));
}));
```

resolved this (without altering the compile target).